# What's the difference between these two download size of mySql

Tags: mysql

Trying to download mysql for a pet project. The downloads page lists out two entries with different file sizes and no mention of what it means

[image]

Any inputs? Is it that the 2.4M one will initiate the installer and then download the rest while being connected to the internet and the 450.7M one will be full package and will not require a connection to get installed?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically ... yes.

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer.html) says this:

> ### MySQL Installer Community Release
>
> Download software from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ to install the Community release of all MySQL products for Windows. Select one of the following MySQL Installer package options:
>
> - Web: Contains MySQL Installer and configuration files only. The web package option downloads only the MySQL products you select to install, **but it requires an internet connection for each download**. The size of this file is approximately 2 MB. The file name has the form `mysql-installer-community-web-VERSION.N.msi` in which `VERSION` is the MySQL server version number such as 8.0 and `N` is the package number, which begins at 0.
> - Full or Current Bundle: Bundles all of the MySQL products for Windows (including the MySQL server). The file size is over 300 MB, and the name has the form `mysql-installer-community-VERSION.N.msi` in which `VERSION` is the MySQL Server version number such as 8.0 and `N` is the package number, which begins at 0.

Comment: How did I miss that? Thanks...will accept when the system allows me to.

Comment: Wouldn't have hurt to put these 2 lines on the download page though :p

Comment: Agreed.  Maybe someone is listening ...